# List from movie database, hyperlink doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm making a sort of movie database website. I want to make a list with 100 movies and when you click on one of the movies, you get more info about the specific movie.

I'm using a big database with movies and this is my query:

```
 public function selectAll() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `movies` LIMIT 200";
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
```

This is what I do in the controller:

```
class MoviesController extends Controller {

  private $movieDAO;

  function __construct() {
    $this->movieDAO = new movieDAO();
  }

  public function index() {
    $this->set('movies', $this->movieDAO->selectAll());
  }
```

And this is what I do in the index:

```
<?php
     echo "<ol>";
      if(!empty($movies)) {
        foreach($movies as $movie){
         echo "<li><a href=\"index.php?page=detail&amp;id={$movie['id']}>{$movie['title']}</a></li>";
              }
          }
     echo "</ol>";
      ?>
```

When I run this I really get a weird result in my HTML:

```
<a href="index.php?page=detail&amp;id=1&gt;Avatar&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=" index.php?page="detail&amp;id=2">Pirates of the Caribbean: At World's End</a>
```

The a href gets really messed up and I don't what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Could you check the values of `$movies` ? Test this in your `foreach` loop `echo '<pre>' . print_r($movie, true) . '</pre>';`

Comment: It's probably due to the quote in the title that's messing up the string, try wrapping the title within the PHP's http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php function to escape every character to HTML friendly characters.

Comment: @AymDev I did what you said and only the movies with id = 1,3,5,7,9.... are showing up.

Comment: You don't get your titles ?

Comment: Yes. I only get the titles from the movies with id = 1,3,5,7,9.

Comment: Like the half of the database is missing @AymDev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to put an **escaped double quote** at the end of the *URL*. This should look like:

```
//                                                      here --v
echo "<li><a href=\"index.php?page=detail&amp;id={$movie['id']}\">{$movie['title']}</a></li>";
```

With **HTML5**, you can ommit the quotes for attribute values which would look like
:

```
echo "<li><a href=index.php?page=detail&amp;id={$movie['id']}>{$movie['title']}</a></li>";
```